# Jquery webcam plugin - error: Flash movie not yet registered

Tags: jquery, webcam

I want to capture image using jquery webcam plugin. I am able to view the video through the player, but i am not able to capture images. I get "error: Flash movie not yet registered" error. What does this mean?
On trying to call webcam.capture function i get an error which says, 'webcam.capture is not a function'.

**Edit:** I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

The problem is solved in this link: https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/issues/14.

The issue is because the test must be in a HTTP URL "`http://....`" and not file URL "`file://....`".

Answer (score 1):

Is the flash section visible when the page loads?  I've found that this is a constant occurrence if the code is in a div that is not visible when the page loads.  Easiest way to get around it is to only load the code when the div is visible:

```
        $("#webcam-cap-div").click(function() {}
```

I'm sure this could be greatly simplified through detection if the div is `:visible` or not ... Further, if you can post code how you use `webcam.capture` that would also help

Answer (score 1):

My problem was actually very silly. I did not have the webcam function wrapped inside jquery's ready event. Wrapping it inside worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#camera").webcam({
         // options
        });
});
```

PS: Like nicolas said, make sure the url is `HTTP`

Comment: After adding $(document).ready(function(){}, It gives below error : 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).webcam is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update your web.xml file with the following :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.swf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but as I answered in this [link](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/issues/14#issuecomment-28769260), this is what I did to solve my problem:

If you REALLY need to use it locally (like i had to), you can change your Global Security Settings (of flash player) to trust files in a determined folder.

- Go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
- Click Edit location
- Then Add Location
- Then choose the folder where your files are

With that configured, I was able to use the plugin locally.